Site in read-only mode, but users are still posting new material
For a day now, every time I go to MathOverflow, it says "This site is currently in read-only mode. We’ll return with full functionality soon." But I also see what appear to be new posts from other users, e.g., the new question,
Conjecture about primes of a special form
posted just a few minutes ago. What is going on here?

Could it be the same problem as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399904/stack-overflow-in-read-only-mode-for-past-2-days ?

That helped – I was able to login using a different browser, so it's some kind of cache problem on the browser I usually use. But if I clear the cache, don't I lose all kinds of useful stuff?

In theory, you shouldn’t. Cache is supposed to store transient data that the browser needs repeatedly to improve speed, but such that it can be redownloaded any time. Clearing cookies can have more visible effects, such as logging you out.

Huh, it didn't say that for me.

@Emil, if you post an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

For me, the thing that cured the problem was deleting the mathoverflow.net cookie and then logging in.

Same experience here.  The problem was happening in the kiwi browser but no others.  Clearing cache solved it.

It has been happening to me for the last several hours. Firefox 128.0.2. Deleting the MO cookies solved the problem.

As @AlexM. said.  It happened to me in Safari. Deleting mathoverflow cookie and then login fixed it.

See staff comment (COMPLETED) Site maintenance - Tuesday, July 23rd 2024, 8 PM - Midnight ET (12 AM - 4 AM UTC, Wednesday July 24 2024). This seems to have been a new problem, and is now fixed.

@jeq While it is possible that the site maintenance on July 23–24 caused some related issues, whatever the staff did did not fix the original problem. New reports of such incidents keep coming in on daily basis, e.g., https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/402049/home-page-is-in-maintenance-mode .

There have been several reports in the past few months that something similar happened to random users on various SE sites, see Stack Overflow in read-only mode for past 2 days.
A user suggests there as a workaround that clearing cache and cookies fixed the issue for them.
EDIT: And now the same thing happened to myself. I can confirm that clearing cookies and site data in Firefox for mathoverflow and stackexchange sites did correct the issue eventually, but only on the second try after about a half day later; it didn’t work when I first tried it immediately when the issue started. It’s also worth mentioning that I had to do it separately on every device that I use to access MO.
